# close app and launch webview on appstart

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, webview

I have made an api request to get some details from my back end service:

I want to dismiss my current view controller and launch a new webpage via a url coming in from the back end:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"X-Service-Code" : @"PP", @"Accept" : @"application/json", @"Content-Type" : @"application/json"};
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:url1 parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


        NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];


        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


        NSString *urlAddress = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:10]valueForKey:@"value"];
        [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]]];


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

The webview is being launched in the background however the view controller is not getting dismissed. Any suggestions?

Comment: you are still displaying self.webView even though you already dismissed self? I am a bit lost there.  

I don't think its the issue of `"because its not performed on the main thread thing"` since if you don't set the completion queue it will always finish at the main queue, unless you specify the completionQueue of afnetwork to use a different queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dismissViewControllerAnimated` needs to be called on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running the dismiss code on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Comment: do I call this procedure on viewdidload or viewwillappear?

Comment: OK so it appears the AFHTTP lib will dispatch its callbacks on the main thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/28932187/8085849 so the dispatch_async isn't needed. In which case, how are you sure that the success: block is actually being called? Is the request definitely completing successfully? i.e. are you sure the failure: block isn't being called instead?

Comment: And it's probably best to make the http request from the viewWillAppear method.

Comment: yes i have verified that the call is executing successfully. but I call the procedure in viwdidload. lemme try viewwillappear

Comment: perhaps since I am getting the url from an api. it is not completing fast enough to load web view?

Comment: Perhaps, maybe are you seeing an empty web view after the screen loads?  Have you checked that *urlAddress* is being populated with a valid URL? Have you tried loading that URL in a browser to check that it loads OK?

Comment: Yes, the webview loads but it is in the background (sometimes does sometimes does'nt)and the app does not close. Expected behavior: App closes and browser or webview launches with the url

Comment: @Ackman I think you need to clarify the UI layout, because your code doesn't close the app or launch a web view. From the code above, I assume you (1) display a parent view controller containing the web view, then (2) open a modal or popover view controller, and then (3) exec the code above to dismiss that and return to the parent, making the web view visible again with the new url loaded. Is that the case?

Comment: Well I do not have a webview in my viewcontroller. I was hoping to just close the app by calling dismiss functionality and launch a browser with the given url(coming in from the api)

Comment: I am relatively new to iOS development let me know if I am missing something

Comment: Ok - if you just want to display the URL in the device's browser then use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];`

Comment: would still need a way to close the background app after the webview launches. Is there a way to do that. Thank you @Julian Goacher